# Для чего нужен async for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

Я не понимаю, для чего нужен `async for`. Пожалуйста, подробно объясните что это такое и как им пользоваться. Приведите простой пример и желательно ещё пример реального использования.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092070/why-do-we-need-async-for-and-async-with

Comment: ответы на такие вопросы нужно искать в документации и на справочных сайтах. не здесь.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Очень коротко:

- Обычный for нужен для итерирования по обычным (синхронным) итераторам и итерируемым объектам
- асинхронный for нужен для итерирования по асинхронным итераторам и итерируемым объектам

Это в общем-то и вся разница. По крайней мере, поверхностная разница, к которой прилагается нижняя часть "айсберга" асинхронного программироваия.

Если какая-то библиотека асинхронная (или поддерживает асинхронность), она может возвращать где-то асинхронный итератор/итерируемый объект с набором результатов. Как про это узнать - посмотреть документацию. Вот пример с `async for` из [документации Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/#queries-the-orm):

```
async for author in Author.objects.filter(name__startswith="A"):
    book = await author.books.afirst()
```

В своем коде можно реализовать свои асинхронные итераторы или итерирумые объекты.

- В обычных итераторах нужно реализовать методы `__iter__` (у итераторов `__iter__` возвращает сам объект, т.е. `self`) и `__next__`, `__next__` выбрасывает исключение `StopIteration` при исчерпании итератора. В итерируемых объектах - просто `__iter__`, который должен возвращать итератор.
- В асинхронных итераторах и итерируемых объектах аналогично, но методы должны быть `def __aiter__` и `async def __anext__`, и `__anext__` должен бросать `StopAsyncIteration` при исчерпании.

Синхронный пример:

```
import time
import random


class Iterator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i <= 0:
            raise StopIteration
        
        self.i -= 1
        
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return random.randint(0, 100)



def main():
    for x in Iterator(10):
        print(x)


main()
```

Асинхронный пример:

```
import asyncio
import random


class AsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = n

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    
    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.i <= 0:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        
        self.i -= 1
        
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        return random.randint(0, 100)



async def main():
    async for x in AsyncIterator(10):
        print(x)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Также есть асинхроные генераторы (функции, возвращающие значения через `yield`), в общем-то единственное синтаксическое отличие от обычных - наличие `async` перед `def`:

```
import asyncio
import random


async def async_generator(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield random.randint(0, 100)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def main():
    async for x in async_generator(10):
        print(x)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Ну и выражения-генераторы с `async for` нужны чтобы собрать результат в список или другой контейнер:

```
async def main():
    result = [x async for x in async_generator(10)]
    print(result)
```

Comment: я бы перефразировал вопрос ТС - "почему не испольозвать только одну конструкцию для синхронных и асинхронных генераторов?"

Comment: @eri, я бы сказал, это другой вопрос. В целом - потому что разработчики языка выбрали такой путь: делать отдельный тип функций, отдельный комплект методов, отдельные конструкции `async for` и `async with`. В какой-нибудь "параллельной вселенной" в Python (в каком-нибудь гипотетическом или реально существующем языке) все функции изначально асинхронные, не нужен явный async (и может быть даже await), и один вариант for.

Comment: в отличии от def, который можно отложить как футуре, фор вполне явно вилит что у него там итерируется

Comment: @eri, я в принципе согласен, тем более что for умеет понимать, что у объекта есть `__iter__` + `__next__` или `__getitem__` + `__len__`, и теоретически можно было туда же добавить поддержку aiter и anext, но видимо "таков путь".